# How to display only association value in prestashop web service response

Tags: web-services, prestashop

How to print only  association value in prestashop web service response.
this is my response url http://www.jpfabtex.com/api/products/?output_format=JSON&ws_key=&display=[id_default_combination,associations]

how to display associations value in json

Answer (score 4):

You can't display only the associations node but you can display by the associations sub-nodes like this:

```
http://www.jpfabtex.com/api/products/? 
output_format=JSON&ws_key=YOURWEBSERVICEKEY&display=[id_default_combination,categories[id],images[img]]
```

This will display de categories and images inside the associations node

Comment: Cool, this is not documented anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

you can not filter products using id_default_combination 
you have to get all the combinations id first and then find each using this way

```
http://www.jpfabtex.com/api/combinations/?output_format=JSON&ws_key=&display=[full]&filter['id']=[implode('|',$combination_id_array)]
```